# Finding number of permutation of size N identical to original Array A on applying a function on all subarrays of A

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

You are given a permutation A of size N consisting of only distinct numbers from 0 to N-1.
MEX(A1, A2, , Ak) is defined as the smallest non-negative integer that
does not include in A1, A2, • • • , Ak
A permutation P of size N is said to be identical to A if MEX of every subarray of A is equal to MEX of every subarray of P. More formally:- `MEX(AL, AL+1, • • • , AR)` = `MEX(PL, PL+1 • • • PR)` where `1 <= L <= R <= N`

Count the number of permutations of size N Identical to A modulo 10** 9 + 7 (the remainder when divided by 10** 9 + 7).
Notes
• Assuming 1-based indexing.
• A subarray is the sequence of the consecutive element of the array.
• A permutation of size N is an array consisting of N distinct integers from 0 to N-1

Example->

```
 N = 4 
 A = [0, 2, 3, 1]
```

Approach

```
There are two permutation. P1= [0, 2. 3, 1]  and P2 = [0, 3, 2, 1] are identical to A. 
For permutation P2 we can see that the MEX of any subarray is equal to the corresponding subarray of A. For example 
• MEX(2) = MEX(3) = 0 (for subarray A[2]) 
• MEX(0, 2, 3) = MEX(0, 3, 2) = 1 (For subarray A[1], A[2], A[3] 
• MEX(3, 1) = MEX(2, 1) = 0 ( For subarray A[3], A[4]) 
• MEX(0, 2, 3, 1) = MEX(0, 3, 2, 1) = 4 For subarray A[1], A[2]. A[3] A[4] Similarly we can check for every subarray. 
Thus answer is 2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What do you or do you not understand ? Is it homework ? If so [follow guideline for homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: As @Alois Christen says, it seems to be a homework.. So please tell us what you have tried so far rather than asking for an answer directly.

Comment: Well its not a homework i got it in a competition and i couldn't get how to approach this problem

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Identical under the `MEX` condition requires the following.

First, `0` must appear where it does in `A`.  This can be seen by which `element arrays give`MEX`of`0`vs`1`.

Now suppose we're constructing an identical array, and numbers `0..k-1` have fit into a range `[i, j]` (while using both `i` and `j`).

If `k` appears outside of that range, `MEX` of a range including all already known and just missing where `k` is is `k`.  And if you include where `k` is, `MEX` is at least `k+1`. Therefore in our identical range, `k` must appear where it did in `A`.

By contrast if `k` appears inside of that range, you can choose any position that you have not chosen already.

This should be enough to find an algorithm to count how many combinations of choices there are in constructing an identical array.

(Note, in the example `0` has to appear where it did in `A`, `1` likewise. Then `2` could be in the remaining 2 choices because it was inside the range, and `3` is also inside the range but only one spot is left.  So there were `1 * 1 * 2 * 1 = 2` choices...)